# Regular expression - text, text, number

Tags: c#, regex, expression

How do you express a regular expression where the string matches the following.

```
text, text, number
```

NOTE:

text = can be any amount of words or spaces.

number = most be 4 digit number.

the commas (,) must be matched too.

As an example, the following string is valid:

```
'Arnold Zend, Red House, 2551'
```

Comment: ...and in which language are you programming? Not all regular expressions are the same.

Comment: Try looking here for a starting point: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx

Comment: What is a `word` for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex pattern for that would be (the parenthesis are capture groups in-case you want to access the individual items:

```
([a-zA-Z\s]{3,}), ([a-zA-Z\s]*{3,}), ([0-9]{4})
```

It matches 2 names and a 4 digit number separated by a comma with the names being at-least 3 characters long. You can change the name character minimum if you'd like. And this is how to check if a string matches this pattern:

```
// 'Regex' is in the System.Text.RegularExpressions namespace.

Regex MyPattern = new Regex(@"([a-zA-Z\s]*), ([a-zA-Z\s]*), ([0-9]{4})");

if (MyPattern.IsMatch("Arnold Zend, Red House, 2551")) {
    Console.WriteLine("String matched.");
}
```

I have tested the expression with [RegexTester](http://www.regextester.com/) and it works fine.

Comment: Won't this regex return true when the words are non-existant? eg = ", , 1234"

Comment: @PaulMcLean Actually yes, I forgot to put a limit there, here is the regex that avoids that problem: `([a-zA-Z\s]{3,}), ([a-zA-Z\s]*{3,}), ([0-9]{4})` This regex ensures the words are at least 3 characters long, you can change the number if you'd like.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the regular expression:

`(?<Field1>[\w\s]+)\s*,\s*(?<Field2>[\w\s]+)\s*,\s*(?<Number>\d{4})`

`\w` = All letters (upper and lower case) and underscores. `+` indicates **one or more**.

`\s` = Whitespace characters. `*` indicates **zero or more**.

`\d` = Digits 0 through 9. `{4}` indicates it must be **four** exactly.

`(?<Name>)` = Capture group name and pattern to match.

You can use this with the `Regex` object in the `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace, like so:

```
  static readonly Regex lineRegex = new Regex(@"(?<Field1>[\w\s]+)\s*,\s*(?<Field2>[\w\s]+)\s*,\s*(?<Number>\d{4})");

  // You should define your own class which has these fields and out
  // that as a single object instead of these three separate fields.

  public static bool TryParse(string line, out string field1,
                                           out string field2, 
                                           out int number)
  {
    field1 = null;
    field2 = null;
    number = 0;

    var match = lineRegex.Match(line);

    // Does not match the pattern, cannot parse.
    if (!match.Success) return false;

    field1 = match.Groups["Field1"].Value;
    field2 = match.Groups["Field2"].Value;

    // Try to parse the integer value.
    if (!int.TryParse(match.Groups["Number"].Value, out number))
      return false;

    return true;
  }
```

Comment: I am quite sure this won't work as OP want. Have you tested with the sample input?

Comment: +1 I like how you put named capture groups. But the `(?<Field1>\w+)\s*` part doesn't account for spaces in the name, just at the end of the name. So it wouldn't match `Arnold Zend, Red House, 2551`. And also `\w` allows for underscores and I don't think OP wants that.

Comment: Oh good point about the lack of spaces between words, I'd have to make an edit for that. I did test it with the sample input, but typo'd my solution. As for the underscore, it's up to the OP of course but it would make logical sense to me. If you had a string such as `Something_Else`, I would assume you want to capture it versus discarding it.

Answer (score 1):

To be unicode compatible:

```
^[\pL\s]+,[\pL\s]+,\pN+$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
[\w ]+, [\w ]+, \d{4}
```

Comment: `\w` allows for underscores and doesn't allow for spaces.

Answer (score 0):

([a-zA-Z\s]+), ([a-zA-Z\s]+), ([0-9]{4})

Comment: `[a-zA-Z]+` doesn't account for spaces in the name.